# Debugging a custom-bib bst file that crashes on book items

Tags: bibtex, debugging, custom-bib

I created my own bibliography file with custom-bib (makebst), but when I run it with a reference to a book I get:

```
$ bibtex PhD
[...normal output]
Database file #1: PhD.bib
You can't pop an empty literal stack for entry oecd2001brc
while executing---line 1504 of file wdsphd.bst
```

The only thing on that line is a high-level `ITERATE` call.

The style was created with these options:

```
%% merlin.mbs  (with options: `head,exlang,annote,seq-no,nm-rvvc,dt-beg,yr-par,xmth,tit-qq,qx,bt-qq,vol-bf,volp-sp,num-xser,pub-date,isbn,issn,doi,english,pp,ord,url,url-nl,nfss,,{}')
%% english.mbs  (with options: `exlang,annote,seq-no,nm-rvvc,dt-beg,yr-par,xmth,tit-qq,qx,bt-qq,vol-bf,volp-sp,num-xser,pub-date,isbn,issn,doi,english,pp,ord,url,url-nl,nfss,,{}')
%% merlin.mbs  (with options: `tail,exlang,annote,seq-no,nm-rvvc,dt-beg,yr-par,xmth,tit-qq,qx,bt-qq,vol-bf,volp-sp,num-xser,pub-date,isbn,issn,doi,english,pp,ord,url,url-nl,nfss,,{}')
```

The code for book items looks like:

```
FUNCTION {book}
{ output.bibitem
  author empty$
    { format.editors "author and editor" output.check
    }
    { format.authors output.nonnull
      crossref missing$
        { "author and editor" editor either.or.check }
        'skip$
      if$
    }
  if$
  format.btitle "title" output.check
  crossref missing$
    { format.bvolume output
      new.block
      format.number.series output
      new.sentence
      format.publisher.address output
    }
    {
      new.block
      format.book.crossref output.nonnull
    }
  if$
  format.edition output
  format.isbn output
  format.doi output
  new.block
  format.note output
  fin.entry
  write.url
}
```

And this is the entry:

```
@book{oecd2001brc,
 author = {OECD},
 doi = {10.1787/9789264193550-en},
 isbn = {9789264186903},
 publisher = {OECD Publishing},
 title = {{Biological Resource Centres: Underpinning the future of life sciences and biotechnology}},
 url = {http://www.oecd-ilibrary.org/science-and-technology/biological-resource-centres\_9789264193550-en},
 year = {2001}
}
```

Is there a way to get a better stacktrace from bibtex? What I have now doesn 't really tell me what is going on. If it can be fixed simply, help would also be appreciated.

Comment: Could you post the options you used to create the style? They are at the top of the `bst` file. That way it will be easier to recreate your style.

Comment: @mafp I was looking for an easy way to share that, thank you. I added them just below the bibtex output.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You found a bug in `custom-bib`, that should be reported to its maintainer.

Specifically, `merlin.mbs` contains in function `format.org.or.pub`, line 6907 ff. the following code that needs to be changed as indicated

```
%<*pub-date&!ay>
      year empty$
        'skip$
        { t empty$ address empty$ and
            'skip$
%<!pub-xc>            { ", " * }           %% removed: swap$ *
%<pub-xc>            { " " * }             %% removed: swap$ *
          if$
          year "year" bibinfo.check
%<dtbf>          bolden
          *
        }
      if$
%</pub-date&!ay>
```

It looks like a copy-and-paste error from the `pub-date&ay` case that follows the code I pasted here.

With this change your `bst` file should contain the function in the following form:

```
FUNCTION {format.org.or.pub}
{ 't :=
  ""
  year empty$
    { "empty year in " cite$ * warning$ }
    'skip$
  if$
  address empty$ t empty$ and
  year empty$ and
    'skip$
    {
      add.blank "(" *
      t empty$
        { address "address" bibinfo.check *
        }
        { t *
          address empty$
            'skip$
            { ", " * address "address" bibinfo.check * }
          if$
        }
      if$
      year empty$
        'skip$
        { t empty$ address empty$ and
            'skip$
            { 
              ", " *                 %% originally: ", " swap$ * *
            }
          if$
          year "year" bibinfo.check
          *
        }
      if$
      ")" *
    }
  if$
}
```

Regarding debugging of `bst` files: there is the `stack$` command that will show you the stack on standard output, but it also flushes the stack, so you almost surely run into errors in the following execution. It is still helpful to see the complete stack at a certain point of the `bst` file. It is less intrusive to show only the topmost stack item as a warning with

```
duplicate$ "On stack:'" swap$ * "'" * warning$
```

or the two top items with

```
duplicate$ "On stack:'" swap$ * "'" * warning$
swap$ duplicate$ "         '" swap$ * "'" * warning$ swap$
```

leaving the stack intact.

Comment: Awesome. I've mailed the author with a reference to this question.

Comment: Uber thanks. I was just in the process of submitting an article to a scientific journal and their bibtex pipeline complained about the exact same error. Had to modify my bst file as indicated here. @mds I hope the maintainer got your notification. Did you get any response so far?

Comment: @Jan-PhilipGehrcke `custom-bib` has not seen any updates for quite some time now, I doubt this will ever get fixed.

Comment: @wds Or did you get a response?

Comment: @Jan-PhilipGehrcke @mafp I did not, but I think the email did go through. Either way, there are other problems that show up (for instance I can't use `citep` for some reason). I'm thinking biblatex is a better choice for the future.

Comment: As of 2014, this bug is still current in many common tex distributions (i.e. my one). This fix has yet again come in handy.

Comment: As of 2021, the same bug in merlin.mbs is still there in the TexLive distribution for Ubuntu.