# Custom .bst file : Does not process entries of type "@book"

Tags: bibtex, custom-bib

I have created a custom `.bst` file using  `makebst` such that it is as per my univeristy PhD guidelines. When I run `BibTex`, it works perfectly for articles, conference proceedings etc. cited. However `BibTeX`fails when I am citing a book. The error I get is

```
 This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (TeX Live 2015)
 The top-level auxiliary file: example.aux
 The style file: thbibstyle.bst
 Database file #1: books.bib
 You can't pop an empty literal stack for entry Arnett96
 while executing---line 1720 of file thbibstyle.bst
 You can't pop an empty literal stack for entry Spitzer78
 while executing---line 1720 of file thbibstyle.bst
```

An example `.tex` file is as follows:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{tanvirTU}
\begin{document}
\title{Title}
\maketitle
Read \cite{Spitzer78, Arnett96}
 \bibliography{books}
  \bibliographystyle{thbibstyle}
\end{document}
```

Here is my `.bst` file: [thbibstyle](http://pastebin.com/raw/QAmBDud9)

Also the bibliography entry are as follows

```
@BOOK{Spitzer78,
   author = {{Spitzer}, L.},
    title = "{Physical processes in the interstellar medium}",
publisher = {New York Wiley-Interscience, 1978.~333 p.},
    year = 1978,
   adsurl = {http://adsabs.harvard.edu/cgi-bin/nph-bib_query?  bibcode=1978ppim.book.....S&db_key=AST},
 adsnote = {Provided by the Smithsonian/NASA Astrophysics Data     System}
}

  @BOOK{Arnett96,
    author = {{Arnett}, D.},
    title = "{Supernovae and Mucleosynthesis: An Investigation of the History of Matter from the Big Bang to the Present}",
    publisher = {Supernovae and Mucleosynthesis: An Investigation of the History of Matter, from the Big Bang to the Present, by D.~Arnett.~Princeton: Princeton University Press, 1996.},
     year = 1996,
    adsurl = {http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/1996snih.book.....A},
   adsnote = {Provided by the SAO/NASA Astrophysics Data System}
   }
```

Also the document class is customized which is: [tanvirTU](http://pastebin.com/03K1GDs5)

Can anyone tell me why this is happening and how to fix it?

For a solution, please refer to this
[Debugging a custom-bib bst file that crashes on book items](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/112195/debugging-a-custom-bib-bst-file-that-crashes-on-book-items?rq=1)

Comment: Please post the code for the `@book` entry with key `Spitzer78`.

Comment: Hmm, is the version of the .bst file you've posted really identical to the one you're using? The reason I ask is that if I try to bibtex a test entry of type @book, I get the same warning, but at line 1679, not line 1720. What gives?

Comment: Did you, by any chance, modify the code inside the function `format.book`? If you did, did you by chance save a copy of the file originally produced by `makebst`?

Comment: @Mico Yes it is okay, because I have deleted the commented lines in .bst file upon uploading it in pastebin. Also the question is edited.

Comment: @Tanvir - Can you confirm that you did not modify the function `book` either?

Comment: @Mico I have not done any modifications to the function `book`. I have checked the code again.

Comment: `TanvirTU` class file couldn't open. Please check

Comment: @ssr1012 Please check now. `tanvirTU` class file should open now.

Comment: @Mico A solution to this is provided in this link 

http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/112195/debugging-a-custom-bib-bst-file-that-crashes-on-book-items?rq=1 


I have modified the `thbibstyle.bst` by going through the above solution.  The modified `bst` file is [thbibstyle_mod.bst](http://pastebin.com/kxhA9QT0) . Please let me know if this fix is alright.

Comment: Sorry, I'm currently on a business trip and can't reply to TeX-related queries. Will be back in a few days.

Comment: @Tanvir Yes the link you provide is a correct fix.  This is a known bug.  This is used in function `format.publisher.address`.  With your current bst, you should also get compilation problems with `InCollection`, `InBook`, `InProceedings`, `Proceedings`.

Comment: @user94293 Thanks. I have corrected my `bst` file. There are no issues as of now.

Comment: @ssr1012 The answer is added.

Comment: @Tanvir: Great.