# makebst generated bibtex file - Error: You can't pop an empty literal stack for entry

Tags: bibtex, custom-bib

When I compile the following latex code:

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\begin{document}
\cite{Lyklema_Fundamentals_1995_} \bibliographystyle{jjap_bml}
\bibliography{tmp}
\end{document}
```

With the following .bib file

```
@book{Lyklema_Fundamentals_1995_,
  address = {Cambridge, Massachusetts},
  title = {the title},
  abstract = {},
  publisher = {a publisher},
  author = {Lyklema, J.},
  month = oct, 
  year = {1995}}
```

And using [this .bst](https://www.dropbox.com/s/9hi6iwtaklkqzpn/jjap_bml.bst?dl=0) generated using makebst ([this script](https://www.dropbox.com/s/9iddpg1rwk1j9tv/jjap_bml.dbj?dl=0)), I get the following error:

```
You can't pop an empty literal stack for entry Lyklema_Fundamentals_1995_
while executing---line 1171 of file jjap_bml.bst
(There was 1 error message)
```

But I cannot understand what the problem is. I can 'view the output anyway' and find the reference is formatted incorrectly as:

"J. Lyklema, the title, (a publisher, Cambridge, Massachusetts1995)."

i.e. there is no comma between the 'location' and 'date' field.

I'd be very grateful for any help.

EDIT: This issue has been resolved by simply editing one line of .bst; please see the first comment by Troy.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)

Comment: Thank you for the Minimal Working Example! This is a bug of makebst. See the solution here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/112278/117534. You just need to make a small change to the `format.org.or.pub` in the bst file manually. After making this edit, your example compiles fine for me.

Comment: Thank you so much! That resolved my issue, you have saved me countless hours of misery! ^^